# Replace every tab (key) with string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

I need to go though a content of element, and replace every tabulator \t with text "(Here's a tab)". How is this possible?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) method on a string:

```
var el = $('#myEl').text();
el.replace(/\t/g, "(Here's a tab)");
```

Note: you **must** use a regular expression with the `/g` modifier to replace every instance of `\t`, using a string for the search will only replace the first occurrence.